# Delete Cookie in Magento on Browser Close

Tags: cookie, delete

I had stuck issue.I had created one cookie but my client needs this cookie should be deleted when the browser is closed.

I had tried many links on the google but not got solution.

Please Help Me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting it's lifetime to `0`?

Comment: @Marius i havent tried having lifetime 0.i will try now

Comment: @Marius it is working fine.Thanks.Can you Post your comment in the Answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the comments...
The cookie lifetime should be set to `0`. This means the cookie will expire at the end of the session.

Comment: It's not working when "Restore previous session" is enabled in browser. Could you please let us know how can we solve this?